IHostedService implementation with dynamic parameter
I wrote a function that creates a permanent timer to execute a function. For example, it calls the desired function every minute.
That function has an input parameter which is a number and I want to create it dynamically. For example, zero is passed in the first run and ten units are added to it in each subsequent run.
This is my class :
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

public class GetProductsEvent : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
     private readonly int _seconds;

     private readonly Timer _timer;
     private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

     public GetProductsEvent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, 
          EventConfiguration eventConfig)
     {
         _seconds = eventConfig.SendInvoiceTimer;
    
         _timer = new Timer(GetTimePeriod());
         _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

         _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
     }

     private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         // var wait = DoWork();
         // wait.Wait();
         DoWork(0);
     }

     private void DoWork(int startRow)
     {
         try
         {
              using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
              {
                  IHostWorker worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostWorker>();
            
                 worker.GetProductsInfo(startRow);
              }
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             // Logging
         }

         _timer.Interval = GetTimePeriod();
         _timer.Start();
     }

     private double GetTimePeriod()
     {
         var runTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_seconds);
         return (runTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         // TODO release managed resources here

         _timer.Stop();
         _timer?.Dispose();
     }

     public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         _timer.AutoReset = false;
         _timer.Start();
     }

     public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         _timer.Stop();
     }
}

The desired function is GetProductsInfo and now I don't know how to change its parameter value

Why don't you inject an additional service via DI that determines/calculates the value?

you can  Introduce a class-level variable _startRow to keep track of the parameter value and
Modify the Timer_Elapsed method to update the _startRow value before passing it to the DoWork method.
Then Update the DoWork method to accept the dynamic _startRow value.
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

public class GetProductsEvent : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly int _seconds;
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private int _startRow; // Class-level variable to keep track of the parameter value

    public GetProductsEvent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, EventConfiguration eventConfig)
    {
        _seconds = eventConfig.SendInvoiceTimer;
        _timer = new Timer(GetTimePeriod());
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _startRow = 0; // Initialize the parameter value
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoWork(_startRow);
        _startRow += 10; // Update the parameter value for the next run
    }

    private void DoWork(int startRow)
    {
        try
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            {
                IHostWorker worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostWorker>();
                worker.GetProductsInfo(startRow);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Logging
        }

        _timer.Interval = GetTimePeriod();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private double GetTimePeriod()
    {
        var runTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_seconds);
        return (runTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Release managed resources here
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}


Class-level _startRow variable: Added to keep track of the current
start row.
Update _startRow in Timer_Elapsed: Incremented by 10 units after
each execution of DoWork.
Pass _startRow to DoWork: Ensures the updated value is used for each
execution.

